# Bootstrap Star Rating with dynamic datasource in asp .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have using bootstarp star rating and download the plugin in follwing URL,

https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating

It is working fine.. But I want to  modify the data source dynamically.

```
 $('#input-1').rating({
                    step: 1,
                    size: 'xs',
                    starCaptions: { 1: 'Poor', 2: 'Can Improve', 3: 'Satisfying', 4: 'Great Work', 5: 'Impressed' },
                    starCaptionClasses: { 1: 'text-danger', 2: 'text-warning', 3: 'text-info', 4: 'text-primary', 5: 'text-success' }
                });
```

StarCaptions & StarCaptionClass needs to change dynamically..

It needs to assign from Javascript variable Or anything else..?

Anyone can help me..

Comment: One thing you could do is, you could re initialize the star rating component with your new data source all over again!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri. Ok But how do assign datasource to "starCaption"  in dynamically..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Code works fine.. There is no `JSON` conversion required.

VB Code :

```
<% Dim Dummy As String ="{ 1: 'Poor', 2: 'Can Improve', 3: 'Satisfying', 4: 'Great Work', 5: 'Impressed' }" %>
```

Javascript Code  :

```
$('#input-1').rating({
    step: 1,
        size: 'xs',
        starCaptions: <%= Dummy %>,
        starCaptionClasses: { 1: 'text-danger', 2: 'text-warning', 3: 'text-info', 4: 'text-primary', 5: 'text-success' }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The starCaptions and StarCaptionClass are JSON objects passed to the function which can be passed from a serverside language such as PHP for example, where using the function `json_encode($array)` you can obtain a json string from within the php variable.

At you code level for example:

```
<script>
  var starCaptionsVar  = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonString; ?>');
  var starCaptionClassesVar  = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonString2; ?>'); 

  // then you can pass it to the  rating
  $('#input-1').rating({
                    step: 1,
                    size: 'xs',
                    starCaptions:starCaptionsVar ,
                    starCaptionClasses: starCaptionClassesVar);
</script>
```

Comment: Im not much into asp, but it is the same concept with their APIs to convert objects to json string

Comment: ok.. What format string format in PHP. Eg.. jsonString ="1:Poor,2:Improve"

Comment: no, its the same JSON object format but as a string variable Eg: `jsonString="{ 1: 'Poor', 2: 'Can Improve', 3: 'Satisfying', 4: 'Great Work', 5: 'Impressed' }";`

Comment: Working fine..  <% Dim Dummy1 As String ="{ 1: 'Poor', 2: 'Can Improve', 3: 'Satisfying', 4: 'Great Work', 5: 'Impressed' }" %>   starCaptions: <%=Dummy1 %>,